# Differences between sys.server_event_* and sys.dm_xe_* when querying SQL Server extended event meta data?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I'm querying SQL Server extended event meta data and I noticed that there are two sets of sources: `sys.server_event_*` and `sys.dm_xe_*`. What are the differences between these two sources? Which one should I use in my queries and why? Can anyone explain this to me or provide some resources for further reading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sys.server_event_*` DMVs contain information about configured XE sessions on the server whereas `sys.dm_xe_*` catalog views and DMVs contain information about the XE packages and objects, with the addition of `sys.dm_xe_database_*` items which are available on Azure SQL DB to track database level sessions. Use them depending on what information you need.